# How can I still use a router in node express and still have a wildcard and params?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

So basically I want my code being able to go mywebsite.com/username and itll take them to their profile.

My app.js has -

```
var user = require('./routes/user');
app.use('/*', user);
```

and then in my user.js I have

```
router.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
    console.log('the user name', req.params.username);
})
```

If I change router.get to just router.get('/') my console.log logs out undefined and if I leave it as router.get('/:username') I get a 404.. I also tried doing app.use('/:username', user) as well but that still didn't work.

Comment: If you want to access like this : mywebsite.com/username  then simply use app.use('/', router); No need to use '/*'

Comment: What he said, also good to note don't even need to include the '/' :)

Comment: But I do app.use('/', index) since that would be my home page and not a user page..

Answer (score 0):

You should't need to have a wildcard like you do on `app.use`

Try something like this.

Also see the express router documentation http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

```
// Required Moduiles
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();


// Add route to get
router.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send(req.params.username)
})

// Add username
app.use('/', router)


// Start express server
app.listen(3030);
```

Update -

Just using `app.use(router)` would do the same thing if all your routes are going to be contained in this new router instance / middleware you are creating in a separate file.

Comment: That above code doesn't work. It returns req.params.username as undefined